# Why is ColdFusion redirects to current page after authentication rather than target page?

Tags: authentication, coldfusion, redirect, coldfusion-9, http-referer

I have a situation where after the user authenticates and it comes back to the current page instead of to the target.

1. User enter the search word and click enter.
2. The search page shows the result on the page with links.
3. The user clicks on the link to see the details page.
4. The details page requires authentication.
5. It redirects the user to the authentication page. At this point in the
   custom_application.cfm page, it shows the HTTP_REFERER as:
   https://devbox.mysite.com/search/?search=calendar
6. The user authenticated and then it comes back to the
   https://devbox.mysite.com/search/?search=calendar page instead of to
   the https://devbox.mysite.com/kb/article/calendar page, which is the
   link that the user clicked and wants to go there.

I found this [article](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/709-coldfusion-cflocation-only-passes-referrer-of-the-referring-url.htm) by Ben Nadal that talks about the issue with CFLocation but it does not provide solutions to the issue or at least I don't feel like there was a solution for my situation.

Here's part of the code in custom-application.cfm file:

```
<cfif cgi.query_string contains "login=1">
    <cfif not cgi.query_string contains "forcelogin=1">
        <cflog text="SERVER_NAME: #cgi.SERVER_NAME#" type="Information" file="Authentication">
        <cflog text="PATH_INFO: #cgi.PATH_INFO#" type="Information" file="Authentication">
        <cflog text="PATH_TRANSLATED: #cgi.PATH_TRANSLATED#" type="Information" file="Authentication">
        <cflog text="SCRIPT_NAME: #cgi.SCRIPT_NAME#" type="Information" file="Authentication">
        <cflog text="QUERY_STRING: #cgi.QUERY_STRING#" type="Information" file="Authentication">
        <cflog text="REMOTE_HOST: #cgi.REMOTE_HOST#" type="Information" file="Authentication">
        <cfif cgi.http_referer contains "search/?search=">
                <cflog text="cgi.http_referer contains: #cgi.http_referer#" type="Information" file="Authentication">
                <cfset tmp=ReReplace(cgi.http_referer, "^.+\.mysite\.com", "")>
                <cfset scriptName=ReReplace(cgi.script_name, "^index.cfm\.+", "")>
                <cflog text="scriptName: #scriptName#" type="Information" file="Authentication">
                <!---<cfset qryString=ReReplace(#tmp#, "/search/?search=", "")>--->
                <cfscript>
                    qryString = replace(#tmp#, "/search/?search=", "", "All");
                </cfscript> 
                <cflog text="qryString: #qryString#" type="Information" file="Authentication">
                <cfset session.preauthurl="#request.author_url#/kb/article/#qryString#">
                <cflog text="After cfset session.preauthurl: #request.author_url#/kb/article/#qryString#" type="Information" file="Authentication">
                <cflocation url="#request.author_url#/authenticate.cfm" addtoken="no">
            <cfelse>
                <!---<cfset session.preauthurl="#cgi.http_referer#">--->
                <cflog text="session.preauthurl-172: #session.preauthurl#" type="Information" file="Authentication">
                <cflog text="cflocation url: #request.author_url#/authenticate.cfm" type="Information" file="Authentication">
                <cflocation url="#request.author_url#/authenticate.cfm" addtoken="no">
        </cfif>
        <!---<cfset session.preauthurl="#cgi.http_referer#">
        <cflocation url="#request.author_url#/authenticate.cfm" addtoken="no">--->
    <cfelse>
        <cflocation url="#request.author_url#/authenticate.cfm" addtoken="no">
    </cfif>
</cfif>
```

And here's part of the code in authenticate.cfm file:

```
    <!--- if this user is not marked as a "licensed contributor", mark them as such.--->
    <cfif session.user.LICENSEDCONTRIBUTOR eq 0> 
        <cftry>
            <CFLOCK SCOPE="Session" TYPE="Exclusive" TIMEOUT="5" THROWONTIMEOUT="Yes">
                <cfquery DATASOURCE="#session.user.USERSDATASOURCE#" NAME="updateContributor">
                   UPDATE Users
                   SET LicensedContributor = '1'
                   WHERE ID = #session.user.id#
                </cfquery>
                <cfset session.user.LicensedContributor = "1">
            </CFLOCK>
        <cfcatch>
            <cfoutput>Error in /authenticate.cfm: An error occurred while trying to log in. Please try again.</cfoutput>
        </cfcatch>
        </cftry>
    </cfif>

    <cflog text="preAuthUrl-63: #session.preAuthUrl#" type="Information" file="Authentication">
    <!---we are now logged in, so redirect somewhere--->
    <cfif session.preAuthUrl eq "">
        <!---not sure where we came from, so redirect to the homepage--->
        <cflocation url="/" addtoken="no">
    <cfelse>
        <!---The tmp here will cause interna server error because it was not defined anywhere.--->
        <cfset tmp=ReReplace(session.preAuthUrl, "^.+\.mysite\.com", "")>
        <cfif session.preAuthUrl contains "login=1">
            <cfif tmp eq "">
                <cflocation url="/" addtoken="no">
            <cfelse>
                <cflog text="tmp-75: #tmp#" type="Information" file="Authentication">
                <cflocation url="#tmp#" addtoken="no">          
            </cfif>
        <cfelse>
            <!---<cfset tmp=ReReplace(session.preAuthUrl, "^.+\.mysite\.com", "")>--->
            <cflog text="final URL: #request.author_url##tmp#" type="Information" file="Authentication">
            <cflocation url="#request.author_url##tmp#" addtoken="no">          
        </cfif>
    </cfif>
</cfif>


<cflog text="http_referer: #cgi.http_referer#" type="Information" file="Authentication">

<!---go back to wherever we came from--->
<cflocation url="#cgi.http_referer#" addtoken="no">
```

And here's what the log shows:

```
========================This is the first time hitting the custom-appliction==================================
"Information","ajp-bio-8013-exec-7","02/25/16","12:17:41","SITE1","SERVER_NAME: devbox.mysite.com"
"Information","ajp-bio-8013-exec-7","02/25/16","12:17:41","SITE1","PATH_INFO: "
"Information","ajp-bio-8013-exec-7","02/25/16","12:17:41","SITE1","PATH_TRANSLATED: \\commonspotshare.mysite.com\commonspot$\DEVSITE\dev.mysite.com\kb\article\index.cfm"
"Information","ajp-bio-8013-exec-7","02/25/16","12:17:41","SITE1","SCRIPT_NAME: /kb/article/index.cfm"
"Information","ajp-bio-8013-exec-7","02/25/16","12:17:41","SITE1","QUERY_STRING: login=1"
"Information","ajp-bio-8013-exec-7","02/25/16","12:17:41","SITE1","REMOTE_HOST: 10.34.3.251"
"Information","ajp-bio-8013-exec-7","02/25/16","12:17:41","SITE1","cgi.http_referer contains: https://devbox.mysite.com/search/?search=calendar"
"Information","ajp-bio-8013-exec-7","02/25/16","12:17:41","SITE1","scriptName: /kb/article/index.cfm"
"Information","ajp-bio-8013-exec-7","02/25/16","12:17:41","SITE1","qryString: calendar"
"Information","ajp-bio-8013-exec-7","02/25/16","12:17:41","SITE1","After cfset session.preauthurl: https://devbox.mysite.com/kb/article/calendar"
"Information","ajp-bio-8013-exec-7","02/25/16","12:17:46","SITE1","preAuthUrl-63: https://devbox.mysite.com/kb/article/calendar"
"Information","ajp-bio-8013-exec-7","02/25/16","12:17:46","SITE1","final URL: https://devbox.mysite.com/kb/article/calendar"
----------------noticed that it never gets to the "http_referer" log at the bottom which is the correct behavior------------------------------------------
========================Now, it hits the target page of "calendar" and it launches the custom-appliction again=====================================================
"Information","ajp-bio-8013-exec-7","02/25/16","12:17:46","SITE1","SERVER_NAME: devbox.mysite.com"
"Information","ajp-bio-8013-exec-7","02/25/16","12:17:46","SITE1","PATH_INFO: "
"Information","ajp-bio-8013-exec-7","02/25/16","12:17:46","SITE1","PATH_TRANSLATED: \\commonspotshare.mysite.com\commonspot$\DEVSITE\dev.mysite.com\kb\article\index.cfm"
"Information","ajp-bio-8013-exec-7","02/25/16","12:17:46","SITE1","SCRIPT_NAME: /kb/article/index.cfm"
"Information","ajp-bio-8013-exec-7","02/25/16","12:17:46","SITE1","QUERY_STRING: login=1"
"Information","ajp-bio-8013-exec-7","02/25/16","12:17:46","SITE1","REMOTE_HOST: 10.34.3.251"
---------------------Noticed the line below shows the target page correctly in session.preauthurl variable------------------------------------------
"Information","ajp-bio-8013-exec-7","02/25/16","12:17:46","SITE1","session.preauthurl-172: https://devbox.mysite.com/kb/article/calendar"
"Information","ajp-bio-8013-exec-7","02/25/16","12:17:46","SITE1","cflocation url: https://devbox.mysite.com/authenticate.cfm"
"Information","ajp-bio-8013-exec-7","02/25/16","12:17:47","SITE1","preAuthUrl-63: https://devbox.mysite.com/kb/article/calendar"
"Information","ajp-bio-8013-exec-7","02/25/16","12:17:47","SITE1","final URL: https://devbox.mysite.com/kb/article/calendar"
----------------------Noticed the line above here (final URL) shows the correct target page--------------------------------------------------------
=======================But it never actually gets to the target page, it went back to the custom-appliction file again as shown below===================================
"Information","ajp-bio-8013-exec-7","02/25/16","12:17:48","SITE1","SERVER_NAME: devbox.mysite.com"
"Information","ajp-bio-8013-exec-7","02/25/16","12:17:48","SITE1","PATH_INFO: "
"Information","ajp-bio-8013-exec-7","02/25/16","12:17:48","SITE1","PATH_TRANSLATED: \\commonspotshare.mysite.com\commonspot$\DEVSITE\dev.mysite.com\kb\article\index.cfm"
"Information","ajp-bio-8013-exec-7","02/25/16","12:17:48","SITE1","SCRIPT_NAME: /kb/article/index.cfm"
"Information","ajp-bio-8013-exec-7","02/25/16","12:17:48","SITE1","QUERY_STRING: login=1"
"Information","ajp-bio-8013-exec-7","02/25/16","12:17:48","SITE1","REMOTE_HOST: 10.34.3.251"
"Information","ajp-bio-8013-exec-7","02/25/16","12:17:48","SITE1","session.preauthurl-172: https://devbox.mysite.com/kb/article/calendar"
"Information","ajp-bio-8013-exec-7","02/25/16","12:17:48","SITE1","cflocation url: https://devbox.mysite.com/authenticate.cfm"
"Information","ajp-bio-8013-exec-7","02/25/16","12:17:48","SITE1","preAuthUrl-63: https://devbox.mysite.com/kb/article/calendar"
"Information","ajp-bio-8013-exec-7","02/25/16","12:17:48","SITE1","final URL: https://devbox.mysite.com/kb/article/calendar"
=======================And again here,it launches the custom-appliction file again and go through a loop===============================================================
"Information","ajp-bio-8013-exec-7","02/25/16","12:17:48","SITE1","SERVER_NAME: devbox.mysite.com"
"Information","ajp-bio-8013-exec-7","02/25/16","12:17:48","SITE1","PATH_INFO: "
"Information","ajp-bio-8013-exec-7","02/25/16","12:17:48","SITE1","PATH_TRANSLATED: \\commonspotshare.mysite.com\commonspot$\DEVSITE\dev.mysite.com\kb\article\index.cfm"
"Information","ajp-bio-8013-exec-7","02/25/16","12:17:48","SITE1","SCRIPT_NAME: /kb/article/index.cfm"
"Information","ajp-bio-8013-exec-7","02/25/16","12:17:48","SITE1","QUERY_STRING: login=1"
"Information","ajp-bio-8013-exec-7","02/25/16","12:17:48","SITE1","REMOTE_HOST: 10.34.3.251"
"Information","ajp-bio-8013-exec-7","02/25/16","12:17:48","SITE1","session.preauthurl-172: https://devbox.mysite.com/kb/article/calendar"
"Information","ajp-bio-8013-exec-7","02/25/16","12:17:48","SITE1","cflocation url: https://devbox.mysite.com/authenticate.cfm"
"Information","ajp-bio-8013-exec-7","02/25/16","12:17:49","SITE1","preAuthUrl-63: https://devbox.mysite.com/kb/article/calendar"
"Information","ajp-bio-8013-exec-7","02/25/16","12:17:49","SITE1","final URL: https://devbox.mysite.com/kb/article/calendar"
=======================And again here,it launches the custom-appliction file again and go through a loop===============================================================
"Information","ajp-bio-8013-exec-7","02/25/16","12:17:49","SITE1","SERVER_NAME: devbox.mysite.com"
"Information","ajp-bio-8013-exec-7","02/25/16","12:17:49","SITE1","PATH_INFO: "
"Information","ajp-bio-8013-exec-7","02/25/16","12:17:49","SITE1","PATH_TRANSLATED: \\commonspotshare.mysite.com\commonspot$\DEVSITE\dev.mysite.com\kb\article\index.cfm"
"Information","ajp-bio-8013-exec-7","02/25/16","12:17:49","SITE1","SCRIPT_NAME: /kb/article/index.cfm"
"Information","ajp-bio-8013-exec-7","02/25/16","12:17:49","SITE1","QUERY_STRING: login=1"
"Information","ajp-bio-8013-exec-7","02/25/16","12:17:49","SITE1","REMOTE_HOST: 10.34.3.251"
"Information","ajp-bio-8013-exec-7","02/25/16","12:17:49","SITE1","session.preauthurl-172: https://devbox.mysite.com/kb/article/calendar"
"Information","ajp-bio-8013-exec-7","02/25/16","12:17:49","SITE1","cflocation url: https://devbox.mysite.com/authenticate.cfm"
"Information","ajp-bio-8013-exec-7","02/25/16","12:17:49","SITE1","preAuthUrl-63: https://devbox.mysite.com/kb/article/calendar"
"Information","ajp-bio-8013-exec-7","02/25/16","12:17:49","SITE1","final URL: https://devbox.mysite.com/kb/article/calendar"
=======================And again here,it launches the custom-appliction file again and go through a loop===============================================================
"Information","ajp-bio-8013-exec-7","02/25/16","12:17:50","SITE1","SERVER_NAME: devbox.mysite.com"
"Information","ajp-bio-8013-exec-7","02/25/16","12:17:50","SITE1","PATH_INFO: "
"Information","ajp-bio-8013-exec-7","02/25/16","12:17:50","SITE1","PATH_TRANSLATED: \\commonspotshare.mysite.com\commonspot$\DEVSITE\dev.mysite.com\kb\article\index.cfm"
"Information","ajp-bio-8013-exec-7","02/25/16","12:17:50","SITE1","SCRIPT_NAME: /kb/article/index.cfm"
"Information","ajp-bio-8013-exec-7","02/25/16","12:17:50","SITE1","QUERY_STRING: login=1"
"Information","ajp-bio-8013-exec-7","02/25/16","12:17:50","SITE1","REMOTE_HOST: 10.34.3.251"
"Information","ajp-bio-8013-exec-7","02/25/16","12:17:50","SITE1","session.preauthurl-172: https://devbox.mysite.com/kb/article/calendar"
"Information","ajp-bio-8013-exec-7","02/25/16","12:17:50","SITE1","cflocation url: https://devbox.mysite.com/authenticate.cfm"
"Information","ajp-bio-8013-exec-7","02/25/16","12:17:50","SITE1","preAuthUrl-63: https://devbox.mysite.com/kb/article/calendar"
"Information","ajp-bio-8013-exec-7","02/25/16","12:17:50","SITE1","final URL: https://devbox.mysite.com/kb/article/calendar"
=======================And again here,it launches the custom-appliction file again and go through a loop===============================================================
"Information","ajp-bio-8013-exec-7","02/25/16","12:17:50","SITE1","SERVER_NAME: devbox.mysite.com"
"Information","ajp-bio-8013-exec-7","02/25/16","12:17:50","SITE1","PATH_INFO: "
"Information","ajp-bio-8013-exec-7","02/25/16","12:17:50","SITE1","PATH_TRANSLATED: \\commonspotshare.mysite.com\commonspot$\DEVSITE\dev.mysite.com\kb\article\index.cfm"
"Information","ajp-bio-8013-exec-7","02/25/16","12:17:50","SITE1","SCRIPT_NAME: /kb/article/index.cfm"
"Information","ajp-bio-8013-exec-7","02/25/16","12:17:50","SITE1","QUERY_STRING: login=1"
"Information","ajp-bio-8013-exec-7","02/25/16","12:17:50","SITE1","REMOTE_HOST: 10.34.3.251"
"Information","ajp-bio-8013-exec-7","02/25/16","12:17:50","SITE1","session.preauthurl-172: https://devbox.mysite.com/kb/article/calendar"
"Information","ajp-bio-8013-exec-7","02/25/16","12:17:50","SITE1","cflocation url: https://devbox.mysite.com/authenticate.cfm"
"Information","ajp-bio-8013-exec-7","02/25/16","12:17:51","SITE1","preAuthUrl-63: https://devbox.mysite.com/kb/article/calendar"
"Information","ajp-bio-8013-exec-7","02/25/16","12:17:51","SITE1","final URL: https://devbox.mysite.com/kb/article/calendar"
=========================And it finally quits in Firefox but in IE it keeps going forever====================================================================
```

Comment: That's what I thought so too. However, to test it out, if the user is already in the details page and he tries to login manually (instead of auto check if the current user has been authenticated or not), then it authenticates fine and comes right back to the details-page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for all the responses and support. I finally figured it out. The reason why it was going in loop was because the way I test if the user is authenticated or not is wrong. Since we're using CommonSpot CMS, I tried to use their [API](http://www.butler.org/commonspot/help/api_help/content/components/login/isloggedin.html) for checking the .isLoggedIn is wrong. I finally had to set the session.mySiteShibboleth.isAuthenticated variable and just check that variable in my details page. If it's not true or not set then redirect the user to the authentication page. This seems to work.

```
<cfif IsDefined("session.mysiteShibboleth.isAuthenticated") >
    <cfoutput>
        mysiteShibboleth exists.
    </cfoutput>
<cfelse>
    <cflocation url="#request.author_url##cgi.script_name#?login=1" addtoken="no" > 
</cfif>
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you are storing refral url of the page in session insted of the current url where u want to come back after authentication. Instead of using cgi.http_referer you should use path_info and query_string (you can skip query_string if your refral URL dose not contains any)

```
  <cfif cgi.query_string contains "login=1">
    <cfif not cgi.query_string contains "forcelogin=1">     
        <cfset session.preauthurl="https://devbox.mysite.com#cgi.path_info##cgi.query_string#">
        <cflocation     url="#request.author_url#/authenticate.cfm" addtoken="no">
<cfelse>
    <cflocation url="#request.author_url#/authenticate.cfm" addtoken="no">
    </cfif>
</cfif>
```

But in case of manual login by user you have to use http_referer.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I tried that but it didn't work The URL on the browser showed: https://devbox.mysite.com/kb/article/index.cfm?login=1 and it ended in internal server error in the authenticate.cfm file under the code line: <cfif session.preAuthUrl contains "login=1">

Comment: This line: https://devbox.mysite.com#cgi.path_info##cgi.query_string# gives me this: https://devbox.mysite.com/login=1 and not: https://devbox.mysite.com/kb/article/calendar where it's the target or destination page. However, even if I managed to get the correct target URL page in the preauthURL session variable, it would still not working.

Comment: The way our CommonSpot CMS work is that every time you access a page, the custom_application.cfm gets fired first. Therefore, the preauthURL session variable gets set correctly the first time when the user click the hyperlink from the search-result page. However, when the user got authenticated and finally landed on the target page, the custom_application.cfm gets called/fired again and this time the Http_referer and preauthURL is incorrect because it was referring to the last page, which is our shibboleth authentication page. And this is where I couldn't figure out.

Comment: which version of ColdFusion you  are uisng and which server? cause path_info should give every thing after your domain name and before query string

Comment: find more deatil on this link https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/reserved-words-and-variables/cgi-environment-cgi-scope-variables/cgi-server-variables.html

Comment: also what value you have in "tmp" variable in  authentication.cfm and you have some logic for redirection in what exactly it  dose?

Comment: I'm using   ColdFusion 10,291717.

Comment: Is path_info giving me the path of the hyperlink that the user clicked or the path of the URL of the page that user is currently on?

Comment: I just tested the cgi_path_info gives me nothing. The hyperlink that the user clicked something like this: https://devbox.mysite.com/kb/article/?artID=calendar and when I logged the cgi.path_info, it gives me blank.

Comment: The "tmp" variable was there to extract the query_string but in the code above, it was wrong. The line <cfset tmp=ReReplace(session.preAuthUrl, "^.+\.mysite\.com", "")> should be defined higher in the code so that it does not error out in the <cfif tmp eq ""> line. By the way, these codes were created my predecessor so I'm also trying to figure how it works.

Comment: Path_info should not be blank I have tested on cf11 and cf9 ( do not have cf 10 to test)  it return the everything after domain name and before query string of current page. I just googled it and found few people also have same people taht path_info was blank. Not sure you also have the same issue https://forums.adobe.com/thread/1157829?start=0&tstart=0

Comment: Right now, I can get the target page without using the path_info is blank but the problem is, it is now going into a loop.

Comment: If I did not prompt the user to login (go through the whole process of custom-application.cfm and authenticate.cfm), the path_info and script_name shows the same when I do a CGI dump. But when I do an authentication, only script_name shows a value not path_info.

Comment: I believe there was a change in behavior beginning with CF10 - CGI.path_info doesn't return what it used to.  To get the complete URI of the currently loaded page, you can use `getPageContext().getRequest().getRequestURI()`.

Comment: Okay, so I bypassed the custom-application.cfm in the details-page and go directly to the authenicate.cfm page but it's still not redirecting back to the detail-page. It shows a "The page isn't redirecting properly." error. In the Else statement of my detail-page, I have this: <cfset session.preAuthUrl="http://#cgi.server_name#/kb/article/#URL.slug#">
 <cflog text="session.preAuthUrl-83: http://#cgi.server_name#/kb/article/#URL.slug#" type="Information" file="Authentication">
 <cflocation url="#request.author_url#/authenticate.cfm" addtoken="no">